# Call a command from a shell script, passing most arguments, allowing arguments with blanks

Tags: ksh, array, arguments

I am have a wrapper `run_sas.sh` around a command `sas` that runs SAS code in batch. A typical call looks like this

```
./run_sas.sh -sysin /my_code/my_program.sas -log /my_log_folder/my_program.log
```

- `run_sas.sh` passes all arguments to `sas` with `./sas $*`.
- `sas` then runs `/my_code/my_program.sas` and writes the log to `/my_log_folder/my_program.log`.
- Then `run_sas.sh` analyzes the arguments it is called with
- and copies the log to `/admin/.hidden_log_folder/my_program_<today's date>.log`

I want to make two changes:

#### Enable multi word parameters

Some customers absolutely want me to use blanks in folder and file names and demand me to run `/their code/their program.sas`, so if I run

```
./run_sas.sh -sysin "/their code/their program.sas" -log "/their log folder"
```

`/their code/their program.sas` and `/their log folder` should be passed single parameters to `sas`

#### Remove a specific parameter

Sometimes I need to run `./sas_utf8` in stead of `./sas` and I am too lazy to maintain a second script, so I would like to allow an extra parameter, so that

```
./run_sas.sh -sysin /my_code/my_program.sas -log /my_log_folder -encoding utf8
```

would call

```
./sas_utf8 -sysin /my_code/my_program.sas -log /my_log_folder
```

instead of

```
./sas -sysin /my_code/my_program.sas -log /my_log_folder
```

How can I do that, preferably in `ksh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `"$@"` instead of `$*` (or `$@`) to keep the arguments intact. It expands each argument as a separate word, as if you used `"$1" "$2"...` Note that with `$*`, glob characters would also be a problem.

To look for the utf8-option, you could loop over the command line arguments, and copy the ones you want to keep to another array, and set a flag if you see `-encoding` and `utf8`.

Then just check the flag variable to determine which program to run, and pass `"${sasArgs[@]}"` to the command.

So:

```
executable="./sas" # The default, for latin encoding

# Inspect the arguments,
# Remember where the log is written
# Change the executable if the encoding is specified
# Copy all arguments except the encoding to the 'sasArgs' array
while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
        -encoding) 
            # change the executable, but do not append to sasArgs
            if [[ "$2" = "utf8" ]]; then
                executable="./sas_u8"               
                shift 2
                continue
            else
                echo "The only alternative encoding already supported is utf8" >&2
                exit 1
            fi
            ;;
        -log) 
            # remember the next argument to copy the log from
            logPath="$2"
            ;;
    esac
    sasArgs+=("$1")
    shift
done

#  To debug: print the args, enclosed in "<>" to discover multi word arguments
printf "Command and args: "
printf "<%s> " "$cmd" "${sasArgs[@]}"
printf "\n"
# exit # when debugging

# Actually run it
"$executable" "${sasArgs[@]}"

# Copy the log using $logPath
# ...
```

The last `printf` calls print the arguments it would run, with `<>` around each, so you can check that the ones with spaces stay intact. (You could run `echo "${sasArgs[@]}"` but it couldn't tell the two arguments `foo` and `bar`, from the single argument `foo bar`.)

---

If we were looking for a single argument, instead of a two-argument pair, that first part could be made a bit simpler with a `for` loop:

```
for arg in "$@" do
    case "$arg" in
        -encoding-utf8) 
            # change the executable, but do not append to the array
            executable="./sas_u8"               
            continue
            ;;
     esac
     sasArgs+=("$arg")
done
```

This could also be converted to plain POSIX sh. The `for` loop makes a copy of the list it's given, so the copied arguments could be stored back in the positional parameters (appending with `set -- "$@" "$arg"`) instead of using an array.

Also, the whole deal could be made a lot simpler if it was known the encoding arguments were at the beginning. Then it would be enough to check `$1` (and `$2`), and they could be removed with `shift`.

*(I tested the above scripts with Bash and the version of ksh93 I had on Debian. I'm not exactly that familiar with ksh, so I may have missed something. But Bash's arrays are copied from ksh, so I expect it should work correctly in both.)*

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Using `"-encoding-utf8"` would simpify the scripting, but our scheduling tool encourages using key-value pears. I siplified the problem for the sake of the question. Tomorrow I will let you know if I could solve the complete problem following your advice and if I needed to switch shell.

Comment: Any objection if I edit your code with some things that might help others with similar problems?

Comment: @DirkHorsten, you can go ahead, though I might re-edit it a bit (since it's my name under the answer etc.) You could also write another answer of your own if you have a significant amount of information to add.

Comment: @DirkHorsten, yep. I changed that second loop back a bit since my point there was mostly the difference between `for` and `while` (no need to explicitly `shift` with a `for`, but can only look at one argument at a time)

Comment: @ilkkacha, This is now up and running, but not in `ksh`, only in `bash` and with some modifications due to the wierd characteristics of our cheduling tool.